# Numpy matrix multiplication with 2D elements

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have an `a` numpy `ndarray` 3x3 matrix that looks like this

```
a =  ([[ uu, uv, uw],
       [ uv, vv, vw],
       [ uw, vw, ww]])
```

Each component is itself a 2D array of size `(N,M)`, so the `a` matrix has a `(3,3,N,M)` shape.

How could I perform a matrix multiplication of `a*a` in a pythonic way?
Using `a@a` throws the following error (for N=1218 and M=540):

> ValueError: shapes (3,3,1218,540) and (3,3,1218,540) not aligned: 540
>   (dim 3) != 1218 (dim 2)

I want to be able to perform this operation as if the elements of `a` where just scalar values where `a@a` does not throw an error related to its shapes since it is a simple 3x3 matrix multiplication.

*Thanks.*

Comment: @ does matrix multiplication on the last 2 dimensions. so you'd have to transpose axes.

Comment: That works as well, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking to perform matrix-multiplication for each element along the last two axes, we can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ijkl,jmkl->imkl',a,a)
```

Sample run for verification -

```
In [43]: np.random.seed(0)

In [44]: a = np.random.rand(3,3,4,5)

In [45]: a[:,:,0,0].dot(a[:,:,0,0])
Out[45]: 
array([[0.71750146, 1.17057872, 1.11135764],
       [0.62938365, 0.86437796, 0.74541383],
       [1.04636618, 1.62011127, 1.35483565]])

In [46]: np.einsum('ijkl,jmkl->imkl',a,a)[:,:,0,0]
Out[46]: 
array([[0.71750146, 1.17057872, 1.11135764],
       [0.62938365, 0.86437796, 0.74541383],
       [1.04636618, 1.62011127, 1.35483565]])
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you very much!